# Blender Python: Import mesh, duplicate mesh, attach suffix, decimate, export?

Tags: python, mesh, export, import

I have written a script that is supposed to do what is listed in the title. Import each .dae in a folder one at a time, duplicate the mesh, decimate both, assign them suffixes, parent them into two empties that are parented, and export. I cannot seem to find a function that passes the TypeError for the duplication. Here is the code:

```
import os
import bpy

# Delete all objects in the scene
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.object.delete()

working_dir = os.getcwd()

# Iterate over all .dae files in the working directory
for file in os.listdir(working_dir):
    if file.endswith(".dae"):
        file_path = os.path.join(working_dir, file)
        
        # Import COLLADA file
        bpy.ops.wm.collada_import(filepath=file_path)
        
        # Get reference to the imported object
        imported_obj = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
        
        # Duplicate imported object
        bpy.ops.object.duplicate(object=imported_obj)
        obj1 = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
        obj1.name = imported_obj.name + "_a250"
        bpy.ops.object.duplicate(object=imported_obj)
        obj2 = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
        obj2.name = imported_obj.name + "_a130"
        
        # Add empty objects
        bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type='ARROWS', radius=1, location=(0, 0, 0))
        base00 = bpy.context.object
        base00.name = "base00"
        bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type='ARROWS', radius=1, location=(0, 0, 0))
        start01 = bpy.context.object
        start01.name = "start01"
        
        # Parent objects
        start01.parent = base00
        imported_obj.parent = start01
        obj1.parent = start01
        obj2.parent = start01
        
        # Decimate objects
        for obj in bpy.data.objects:
            if "_a250" in obj.name:
                obj.modifiers.new("Decimate", type='DECIMATE')
                obj.modifiers["Decimate"].ratio = 0.75
            elif "_a130" in obj.name:
                obj.modifiers.new("Decimate", type='DECIMATE')
                obj.modifiers["Decimate"].ratio = 0.5
            bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier="Decimate")
        
        # Export COLLADA file
        bpy.ops.wm.collada_export(filepath=file_path)
```

Does anyone have any ideas of what else I could use to make this work? I am using blender 3.4 Thanks!

The error usually experienced is a variation of this:

> TypeError: Converting py args to operator properties:

Fixed the TypeError! You can use this:

```
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = imported_obj
    bpy.ops.object.duplicate()
    obj1 = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
```

The thing now not currently working is the decimate functions, any ideas why?

Comment: That code to add a modifier and change the ratio should work. What error are you getting?

Comment: Stop using `bpy.ops`, this will throw errors if the context is wrong.

Comment: Use `os.scandir` instead of `os.listdir`, `os.scandir` is faster.

Comment: thanks everyone, I will apply these changes, and see if I made any mistakes.